# bootstrap_find_resource do not serve local files

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-bootstrap

I am using Flask-Bootstrap package for my Flask application, however when I am creating a template as described in docs:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html %}

<!-- Rest of the template is here -->
```

page source displays this:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't know why this resource is taken from `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` instead of local files in Flask-Bootstrap package.

`cdnjs.cloudflare.com` is referred in more places in page source code.

Can I somehow change this behavior in my template, to make it serve resources from local directory?

**base.html** template uses bootstrap_find_resource template filter, so I guess it have something to do with CDN settings, how can I change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your configuration :

```
app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True
```

Check out [Flask-Bootstrap](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/configuration.html) link for more info.